# Performance issues with asp.net &/or jQuery - Safari iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, asp.net, performance, jquery-ui, mobile-safari

I've built an asp.net (VB) web app at work that uses SQL Server backend for data with stored procedures. The front end is built in VS2008 and also uses bits of jQuery, Dundas charts, JavaScript, CSS etc.

It's largely accessed on desktop machines but also mobile. On the iPad 2 & 3, iPhone 4/4s performance is great and pages load close to instantly. I've just received an iPhone 5, and accessing the site in Safari and Chrome takes between 2x to 5x longer to load, and some image buttons/JavaScript is slow/unresponsive?

Has anybody else run into any problems, or does anyone know a good way I can go about testing what is the cause of the problem, or the best way to develop a workaround?

Thanks in advance (first post but have used the fantastic answers from this site constantly in the last 2 years).

Comment: Sorry...I'm an idiot. It's actually just the WiFi issues people are reporting. I get 20-50x slower downloads on my iPhone 5 than my 4s when tested side by side.